# How to method chaining in pandas to aggregate a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate, method-chaining

I want to aggregate a pandas DataFrame using method chaining. I don't know how to start with the DataFrame and just refer to it when aggregating (using method chaining). Consider the following example that illustrates my intention:

Having this data:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['john', 'diana', 'rachel', 'chris'],
    'favorite_color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red']
})

my_df
#>      name favorite_color
#> 0    john            red
#> 1   diana           blue
#> 2  rachel          green
#> 3   chris            red
```

and I want to end up with this summary table:

```py
#>    total_people  total_ppl_who_like_red
#> 0             4                       2
```

Of course there are so many ways to do it. One way, for instance, would be to build a new DataFrame:

```py
desired_output_via_building_new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'total_people': [len(my_df)],
    'total_ppl_who_like_red': [my_df.favorite_color.eq('red').sum()]
    })

desired_output_via_building_new_df 
#>    total_people  total_ppl_who_like_red
#> 0             4                       2
```

***However***, I'm looking for a way to use "method chaining"; starting with *my_df* and working my way forward. Something along the lines of

```py
# pseudo-code; not really working
my_df.agg({
    'total_people': lambda x: len(x),
    'total_ppl_who_like_red': lambda x: x.favorite_color.eq('red').sum()
    })
```

---

I can only borrow inspiration from `R/dplyr` code:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

my_df <- 
  data.frame(name = c("john", "diana", "rachel", "chris"),
             favorite_color = c("red", "blue", "green", "red")
             )

my_df |> 
  summarise(total_people = n(),                                     ## in the context of `summarise()`,
            total_ppl_who_like_red = sum(favorite_color == "red"))  ## both `n()` and `sum()` refer to `my_df` because we start with `my_df` and pipe it "forward" to `summarise()`
#>   total_people total_ppl_who_like_red
#> 1            4                      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for processing one `Series`:

```
df = my_df.favorite_color.apply({
    'total_people': lambda x: x.count(),
    'total_ppl_who_like_red': lambda x: x.eq('red').sum()
    }).to_frame(name=0).T
print (df)
   total_people  total_ppl_who_like_red
0             4                       2
```

General solution for processing `DataFrame` with [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) - then pandas processing input DataFrame, if use `apply` or `agg` processing columns separately:

```
df = (my_df.pipe(lambda x: pd.Series({'total_people': len(x), 
                                     'total_ppl_who_like_red': 
                                        x.favorite_color.eq('red').sum()}))
           .to_frame(name=0).T)
print (df)
   total_people  total_ppl_who_like_red
0             4                       2
```

---

```
df = my_df2.pipe(lambda x: pd.Series({'total_people': len(x), 
                           'total_ppl_who_like_red': 
                               x.favorite_color.eq('red').sum(),
                           'max_age':x.age.max()
                          }).to_frame(name=0).T)
print (df)
   total_people  total_ppl_who_like_red  max_age
0             4                       2       41
```

Comment: Many thanks! I now realize my example was too minimal. Is the second solution (i.e., `DataFrame.pipe`) enabling us to aggregate more than one column? For example, consider `my_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john', 'diana', 'rachel', 'chris'], 'favorite_color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red'], 'age': [30, 40, 41, 23]})`.  Can we extend your 2nd solution to also _add_ an aggregate for maximum of `age`?